# Как использовать Background image в React styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, background, nextjs, styled-components

Как использовать картинки background в styled components? Везде пишут, что достаточно провести импорт и вписать background: url(${myImg}), но у меня по каким-то причинам это не работает.

Использую next.js.

```
import img from '../../src/img/test.bmp';

export const CellEmpty = styled.div`
  background: url(${img}); // здесь ide подчеркивает img, см ниже
`;
```

Ошибка:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'StaticImageData' is not assignable to
> parameter of type
> 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes,
> HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes> & {
> ...; } & ICellProps, any>>'.   Type 'StaticImageData' is not
> assignable to type 'CSSObject'.     Index signature for type 'string'
> is missing in type 'StaticImageData'.

Answer (score 0):

лучше использовать `background-image`. Так как вернется строка, то внутри нужно обернуть кавычками.

вот так должно работать:

```
background-image: url('${img}');
```